# How to resolve "Illegal double ... value found during parsing" on a mysql insert?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For a year or so I've used a php page to import ebay orders from a csv file into a mysql database. This is how my query looks:

```
 "INSERT INTO orders VALUES (0, {$fname}, {$lname}, {$address1}, {$address2}, {$town}, {$county}, {$postcode}, {$country}, {$tel}, {$email}, '', {$postage}, {$subtotal}, {$total}, {$basket},'', 'eBay', now(), 'GBP', 'paypal', 1, '', 1, {$txnId}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE txnid=txnid, complete=complete, new=new, time=time;";
```

Last week I started receiving the error "Illegal double (txnId varchar) value found during parsing" on some orderlines and it prevents me from importing further orders.

I've read suggestions that this is because the value $txnId is not correctly delimited. I have tried changing it to both `'{$txnId}'` and `\'{$txnId}\'`, which works but in both cases it results in the non-problematic orders having their txnIds prefixed with ''.

Can anyone help me find a way to amend my query so that I no longer receive this error on certain orders? And, as a bonus, can anyone explain to me exactly what this error message means and why it only affects certain orders as I'd like to understand this problem as well as fix it.

Comment: Looks like MySQL is interpreting the `$txnId` as a double (it probably has a lowercase *e* in it). With all the unquoted strings in your statement, I'm surprised it works at all

Comment: Just checked and they have an upper case E. Can you explain why this results in that value being passed as a double?

Comment: This is one reason writing prepared statements with something like PDO is very valuable.  Not only would it mitigate this problem, but it would likely also speed up your inserts considerably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'E' in the variable may have confused the system into thinking it as a double value because double values can expressed as something similar to "7.012E-5"

Comment: How can I sanitize the $txnId varchar before inserting it? I tried wrapping it in quotes if it contains E. But there are a lot of entries that contain E that don't parse as a double, and they end up being entered into the table with '' before them, which causes problems in how I handle the data later on.

Comment: I'm thinking '{$txnId}' should work, but I don't understand why it would prefix the field with ''.  

Can you give me a sample of a problematic data value vs. a non-problematic one?

Comment: Sure. `6L831105EP011602` and `71V72876YH791094` parse fine, but `546635980E5898057` parses as a double. I can provide more later if you need them.

Comment: I've tried inserting these sample data into a test database, and I could not get '{$txnId}' to prepend '' on any data value, even empty ones.  I did get the complaint about the double value when I took out the string delimiters.